# How to tokenize word with hyphen in Spacy

Tags: tokenize, spacy

I want to tokenize bs-it to ["bs","it"] using spacy, as I am using it with rasa. The output which I get from is ["bs-it"]. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom rules to spaCy's tokenizer. spaCy's tokenizer treats hyphenated words as a single `token`. In order to change that, you can add custom tokenization rule. In your case, you want to tokenize an `infix` i.e. something that occurs in between two words, these are usually hyphens or underscores.

```py
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

infix_re = re.compile(r'[-]')

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab,infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp("bs-it")
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

**Output**

```
['bs', '-', 'it']
```