# spaCy custom tokenizer to separate word with underscore and also to include the whole word

Tags: regex, nlp, spacy, tokenize, linguistics

After referring to the link: [How to tokenize word with hyphen in Spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62500973/how-to-tokenize-word-with-hyphen-in-spacy)
I got to know how to tokenize by separating words containing hyphen/underscore but my requirement is to tokenize by separating it and also to include that whole word.
For example:
Input: bs_it
Output: ["bs", "it", "bs_it"]

Comment: A tokenizer is "not supposed" to add new data to the input string. I think you're trying to do 2 different tasks at the same time (data augmentation + tokenization). Is there a particular reason you want to do it here ? Would you consider performing data augmentation before the tokenizer ?

Comment: I thought tokenizer should be first in the pipeline. Yes, it is fine for me if data augmentation before tokenizer in the pipeline works.

Comment: This is a pretty weird thing to do. What do you want the resulting document to look like? Like if the initial text is `I have a bs_it` the output should be `I have a bs it bs_id`? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: While searching bs_it, I want to highlight all the occurrences of bs, it and bs_it. Yeah you are right, it would be weird. Thanks for the insights. I will try to handle this requirement outside the spaCy pipeline.